# How to determine if the user has scrolled a scrollable multi-line EditText to the bottom of the text?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

In an Android app written in Kotlin, I'm using a scrollable multiline EditText. The EditText is not inside a ScrollView. Instead, I'm using the scrolling feature of the EditText class. I set an OnScrollChangeListener on the EditText like this

```
class MyFrag : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?, savedInstState: Bundle?): View? {
        var view: View? = null
        try {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstState)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_mine, container, false)

            val editText: EditText = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_input)
            editText.setOnScrollChangeListener(ScrollHandler())
        }
        catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e("MyAppTag", "MyFrag.onCreateView failed", ex)
        }
        return view
    }


    private inner class ScrollHandler : OnScrollChangeListener {
        override fun onScrollChange(view: View?,
                scrollX: Int, scrollY: Int, oldScrollX: Int, oldScrollY: Int) {
            try {
                Log.d("MyAppTag", "Scroll handler: $scrollX, $scrollY, $oldScrollX, $oldScrollY")
            }
            catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("MyAppTag", "ScrollHandler.onScrollChange failed", ex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The scroll handler is working as I expected and is logging the scroll events. What code can I add to the onScrollChange method that will determine if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the text?